# Flexbox contents don't stretch to fit container, despite not having their heights set anywhere

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically the title. I have a flex container, that has its height set to a specific value (100% but its parent is a specific one. I want the items to fill the available space, regardless of the content in them (specifically the second item, the treeview1, which has its overflow set to scroll. However, the items simply don't stretch to fill. Do you have any suggestions for me? Thanks :)

```css
html, body, .container-fluid, .row, #left-panel {
  height: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-view {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.buttons-placeholder {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.buttons-placeholder button {
    margin: 2px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.btn-success {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="left-panel">
      <div class="buttons-placeholder">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load Batch</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Batch</button>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-view"></div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Sorry if the formatting is off, i'm kind of new to this.
Edit 2: Cleaned up the code a bit.

Comment: where is your `.thumbnail-image-container` ?

Comment: @SushmitSagar Sorry, updated the question. The image-container is not needed here, i copied it by accident

Comment: You should also tag this with the CSS framework you are using; resp. provide a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set `display: flex; flex-direction:column; height: 100vh;` to the `row` class and set `flex: 1` for the element that needs to fill the remaining space. In addition, try to set `flex-direction: column` for the flex container:

```
html, body, .container-fluid, .row, #left-panel {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
}

.thumbnail-view {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: lightpink;
    flex: 1;
 }

 .buttons-placeholder {
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
  }

  .buttons-placeholder button {
      margin: 2px;
      flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .btn-success {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

and html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="buttons-placeholder">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load Batch</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Batch</button>
          </div>
          <div class="thumbnail-view"></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thing is, i want the thumbnail-view to scale to fit regardless of how many siblings it has, and height: 90% (or any pixels) will clash with that if i add more :

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much :) I assume the problem was i was not setting flex: 1 to the stretching element, right? I tried setting flex: 1 to the container and it did nothing, but this here works

Comment: @PeterPetkov I am glad that it helped to you!:) yeah, you are right. `flex: 1` is for the element that needs to fill the remaining space

Answer (score 0):

I guess that "treeview1" element that you've mentioned is actually element with class "thumbnail-view". That element doesn't want to stretch because it is not a flex element. The only flex wrapper that you have is the one with "buttons-placeholder" class. So, what you need to do is to add

```
style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;"
```

to element that currently has "col-md-2" class.